# C program function error

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

This code has to get coordinates and write them to the `coords` array, and also return the number of coordinates that have been entered.

The code has to stop once the user enters `0 0` but the code should not save it.

For example if I enter `1 2 3 4 0 0` the code will set the array to `(1,2) (3,4)`.

But in this code when I enter `0 0` it show me error, and once I enter the numbers at first the print show me just zeros.

```
int coordinatesread(double coords[][DIM], int n)
{
    double columnin, rowin;
    int row=0;
    while(row!=n-1)
    {
        scanf ("%lf",&columnin);
        scanf ("%lf",&rowin);
        if (columnin==0 && rowin==0)
        {
            return row+1;
        }            
        else
        {
            coords[row][0]=columnin;
            coords[row][1]=rowin;
            ++row;
        }

       printf("%.3lf %.3lf", coords[row][0], coords[row][1]); /* TEST */

    }
    return row+1;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? The reason it's printing 0 is because you're printing using the `row` variable after you've incremented it.

Comment: @Welbog means "the reason it's printing error".  You need to printf `coords[row-1][0], coords[row-1][1]`.  Also, stop messing around with `double` if that's not what's intended.  You reading in `float`'s, your comparing to `int`'s, your typing in `int`'s.

Comment: @jiveturkey, I don't know why you think that. STD claims it's printing 0, and if the `coords` array is zeroed out, then the reason is because `row` is incremented before being used to print. I have no idea what's causing the error because STD has not provided an error.

Comment: I removed the printf line and it still show me error after I enter 0 0

Comment: What is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: the error that I get : " thenameofthecode.exe has stopped working"

Comment: The problem is not likely within the snippet you've provided. You should try narrowing the problem down.

Comment: but also the printf I changed it to row-1

Comment: and it's still show me 0.000

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Has your `coords` array been allocated enough space? Without the aforementioned MCVE, we can't determine that, and for all we know, `coords` is simply too small to hold your data.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when compiling with *all* warning flags on?

Comment: when I run it once I enter the coordinates for example 1 1 it show me 0.000 0.000 and one I enter 0 0 the program stop working and exist

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you print coords[row][0] and coords[row][1] you are actually sending to stdout the next coordinates which are not still entered by the user. You are sending to stdout undefined values and not the values you entered. The line `printf("%.3lf %.3lf", coords[row][0], coords[row][1]);` should be `printf("%.3lf  %.3lf\n", coords[row-1][0], coords[row-1][1]);` And add the next to line `\n` otherwise the information printed is illisible.

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 2

int coordinatesread(double coords[][DIM], int n)
{
    double columnin, rowin;
    int row=0;
    while(row!=n-1)
    {
        scanf ("%lf",&columnin);
        scanf ("%lf",&rowin);
        if (columnin==0 && rowin==0)
        {
            return row+1;
        }
        else
        {
            coords[row][0]=columnin;
            coords[row][1]=rowin;
            row++;
        }
       printf("%.3lf  %.3lf\n", coords[row-1][0], coords[row-1][1]); /* TEST */
    }
    return row+1;
}

int main(void)
{
    double cords[5][2];
    int n = 5;

    coordinatesread(cords, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, let's see. The problem in your code is that you are incrementing the value of `row` before printing the values in `coords[row][0]=columnin`

You are not going to print a line if the values are both zero, so you can move this line:

> printf("%.3lf %.3lf", coords[row][0], coords[row][1]);

Right before this one:

> ++row;

The new code should look like this:

```
int coordinatesread(double coords[][DIM], int n)
{
    double columnin, rowin;
    int row=0;
    while(row!=n-1)
    {
        scanf ("%lf",&columnin);
        scanf ("%lf",&rowin);
        if (columnin==0 && rowin==0)
        {
            return row+1;
        }            
        else
        {
            coords[row][0]=columnin;
            coords[row][1]=rowin;
            printf("%.3lf %.3lf", coords[row][0], coords[row][1]);
            ++row;
        }
    }
    return row+1;
}
```

PD:
Notice that your code does not work fine if you want to scan N valid coordinates, because the last one will be ignored. The problem is here:

> while(row!=n-1)

If you have decided to use `while` loop instead of `for`, you should iterate until row = N. Let's suppose N = 3. If you want to scan 3 valid coordinates, the loop will iterate while N != 2. This will scan only two of them (when row = 0 and row = 1). Change it to:

> while(row!=n)

In addition, when you are iterating over an array (or a table in this case), using `for` is better than `while`. Both are correct, but `for` is more stylized. If you change it, the code look like this:

```
int coordinatesread(double coords[][DIM], int n)
{
    double columnin, rowin;
    for(int row = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%lf",&columnin);
        scanf ("%lf",&rowin);
        if (columnin==0 && rowin==0)
        {
            return row+1;
        }
        else
        {
            coords[row][0]=columnin;
            coords[row][1]=rowin;
            printf("%.3lf %.3lf", coords[row][0], coords[row][1]);
        }
    }
    return row;
}
```